# Hide a link with a specific class and attribute

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I have this html.

```
<a class="link" href="www.website.com?id=233253">test1</a>
<a class="link" href="www.website.com?id=456456">test2</a>
```

How can I hide one of these links by using the href attribute, and just the last numbers (233253), to hide the link with this href attribute and the class "link"?

This is not a working code, just something i put together to explain it better.
getElementsByTagName('a').class('link').href="*233253"

Update:
Unfortunately it has to be pure javascript, not using a library, and it has to work on IE6.

Update2:
I don't have access to the html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

function hideLinks(className, ids) {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var max   = links.length;

    for (var i=0; i<max; i++) {
        var link   = new RegExp("(\s*)"+ className +"(\s*)");
        var isLink = link.test(links[i].className);

        if (isLink) {
            for (var j=0; j<ids.length; j++) {
                var regexp = new RegExp(ids[j] + "$");
                var hasId  = regexp.test(links[i].href);

                if (hasId) {
                    links[i].style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    hideLinks("link", [233253]);
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<a class="link" href="www.website.com?id=233253">test1</a>
<a class="link" href="www.website.com?id=456456">test2</a>


</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**: I posted a new version after reading your comment about encapsulating the functionality inside a function. This one should work just as well as the previous version.

Comment: Thanks ;) Is there a way to make this code more compact? It has to be as short a possible, readability is not important.

Comment: Surely you can do this yourself: just remove whitespace and shorten variable names.

Comment: I can't figure out how to input the number from a variable. I'm trying to create a function from it, so I can reuse it, but I don't quite know how and there to put the variable that holds the number.  /233253$/  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

[**edit**]: code was somewhat sloppy, should work now. Including the split method (see comments).

Loop through the a elements, check href and apply the hiding. Like this:

```
var refs = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i=0;i<refs.length;i++) {
       if (
             refs[i].href &&
             refs[i].href.replace(/(\d+$)/,'$1').match('[your value to match]')
          ) {
           refs[i].className = refs[i].className.replace(/link/i,'');
           refs[i].style.display = 'none';
       }
}
```

OR

```
for (var i=0;i<refs.length;i++) {
   var hs = refs[i].href.split(/=/)[1];
   if (  hs.match([your value to match]) ) {
       refs[i].className = refs[i].className.replace(/link/i,'');
       refs[i].style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```

Comment: You can also split the href (refs[i].href.split(/=/)) and take element 1 of the resulting array to compare with your condition.

Comment: Is that a better solution. How would I do that with your code?

Comment: I couldn't get your script working. I get this error in Firebug. Firebug's log limit has been reached. %S entries not shown.  Preferences  
missing ; after for-loop initializer
[Break on this error] for (var i=0,i<refs.length;i++) {\n

Comment: Still doesn't work. I don't get any error message now, but it won't hide the link. My HTML: http://pastebin.com/d1963ce64

Comment: hs.match(233253) => hs.match('233253')

Comment: The last pastebin you posted has expired. Can you share the code again?

Answer (score 4):

Using jQuery:

```
$("a.link[href$='233253']").hide();
```

The $= attribute selector matches all elements where the selected attribute ends with the given value.

Comment: Thanks, I would really like to use jQuery, but I don't have access to it where this is going to be used.

Answer (score 1):

No offense but creating loops seems like a workaround to me. If you could add unique id's to the links that would obviously be the preferred method.

After that you could use 'getElementById' to set a different class to hide the particular link.

Comment: or even just set CSS rules and do away with JS altogether. #link233253 { display: none }

Answer (score -1):

What distinguishes one link from another? If you know that on the server side then add appropriate classnames and which will be hidden, in a static way, from the CSS.

Dynamically determining what needs hiding will require you to dynamically generate your javascript snippet, unless you render this inside the HTML.

**Update:** If you don't have access to the generated HTML then my post does not help you.